# Checking the existence of a variable

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have a very small program that I'd like to be able to compile on multiple platforms.  Some platforms offer `sys_signame` in `signal.h`, but others do not, and I'll need to provide an alternative.  Using `#define`/`#ifndef` is not an option: these are platform headers, not mine, and there doesn't seem to be any particular `#define` line that corresponds with the presence of `sys_signame` across multiple platforms.

I don't want to add a special case for each platform.  This is a very small program that only a few people are going to see, and it's not going to be used in any sort of production environment.  I don't yet know what operating systems it will be used on.  It's not worth my time to test it thoroughly.  I'll save stuff like that for more important programs.

How can I test for the presence of a global variable such as `sys_signame`?

Comment: Your question sounds like an instance of the XY problem. What is it that you want to do with `sys_signame`?

Comment: How can you compile the code if the variable is not present?

Comment: @FUZxxl Retrieve signal names and display them to the user in a short form.

Comment: @Anton.P Yes, that's the issue. ;)  If the variable isn't present, I need to define it myself.

Comment: @Zenexer Use `strsignal()` from POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it - you need to either create an alternate array that will work on all platforms, depending on the list of signals you are ready to process.

```
const char* my_sys_signame[] = { NULL, "HUP", "INT", ...  "USR2" };
```

Finally, if you must check for the existence of sys_signame, your only option is to do something like:

```
#ifdef NSIG
// have sys_signame
#else
// does not have sys_signame
#endif
```

Comment: Please notice that `strsignal(sig)` outputs a descriptive string for `sig`, not the signal name itself. For example, `strsignal(SIGKILL)` usually returns something like `"killed"`.

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl, removed this line as it was incorrect like you pointed out.

Comment: All platforms that I've looked at define `NSIG`, but some don't define `sys_signame`.  For example, Linux doesn't have `sys_signame`, but Mac OS X does; both have `NSIG`.  BSD lacks supposedly `strsignal`, but I haven't tested that.  Signal numbers are not the same across platforms, unfortunately, but I can get around that using macros and `#ifdef`.

Comment: @Zenexer - signal numbers are defined by POSIX, and should be the same everywhere. Can you give an example that shows the opposite?

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Only a small subset of signal numbers are specified by POSIX (in the section for the [kill](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) command). The description of `<signal.h>` doesn't specify signal numbers at all.